# Is there a way to use the HTML5 Gamepad API with multiple windows or tabs in Firefox?

Tags: html, api, firefox, gamepad

I'm designing an app that utilizes input from a gamepad using the HTML5 Gamepad API.  I have the app working in both Firefox and Chrome, however Firefox does not seem to allow a second Window or Tab to access the gamepad after a previous tab has accessed it.  I don't need both to access the api at the same time, I only need one to be able to access the api after the other.  Chrome does not have this problem.  I also tested using html5gamepad.com with the same results.  Does anyone have a way to release the gamepad from one window when it loses focus so it is available to another window?  My customer will be using Firefox. 
 Thanks.

Comment: Any development on this? I have the same issue!